# How to convert byte[] values to decimal?

Tags: java, byte, arrays, wireshark, data-conversion

I'm using wireshark and I need to take two bytes (attached image) and have it's decimal value:

[image]

My goal is to take this `byte[]` which is in hex value and parse it to decimal.

Sure, I know how to make **one** value to decimal which is easy, but I don't know how to make these two, should I make a sum between them or is there any other way to make it?

I didn't find any value which is different then this which the left value is not `00`.

Comment: "*I didn't find any value which is different then this which the left value is not 00.*" What do you mean by this?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I meant to say that I didn't find any length value which is like 0100 or greater so I would find the solution by myself, thus I need help to understand how to parse this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always big endian (network byte order), try this.

```
    byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x16};
    System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getShort());  // => 22
```

If byte array length is 4, use `getInt()` instead of `getShort()`

Comment: `getInt()` threw me this: `java.nio.BufferUnderflowException()`

Comment: Use ```getInt()``` only when byte array length >= 4.

Comment: Use `getInt()` only when you're fetching a 4-byte value.